# Получить только те продукты который запросил юзер

Tags: python, sqlite

```
    user_request=input("Enter product name: ")
    ###какой код
    result=cur.execute("SELECT product_number FROM  products WHERE product==?", user_request,) 
    )      
    print(result)
```

нужно сделать так, пользователь получил остатки только одного продукта который просил.

Comment: но я получаю такую строку: <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000018E79DD2740>

Comment: print(result.fetchall())

Comment: Большое спасибо за оперативны ответ. Работает, теперь еще возникли вопросы:
1. получаю ответ такого вида, [(35,)], как получить ответ такого вида 35
2. Как использовать оператор LIKE в моем запросе.
Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: Чтобы получить нормальный лист ответов - можно сделать так: [i[0] for i in result.fetchall()], оператора LIKE используется примерно так: ``SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... LIKE '%текст%' ``, где текст - ваш запрос (то, что вы ищете)

Comment: а моем случии так?:
"SELECT product_number FROM  products WHERE LIKE %product%", user_request,) 
но выдает ошибку такого вида:
sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input

Comment: Вы не выбрали столбец, точнее: WHERE product LIKE '%{user_request}%'

Comment: все работает, большое спасибо.